# How to concatenate DNS TXT records?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, txt-record

Google Search Console is asking me to add a TXT record to my domain name, like

```
google-site-verification=EQZs1xbCh8hu90LwVGhWEcYUYCGH6BDSBE68
```

But I already have a TXT record for SPF like

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:68.66.123.12 include:spf.myhosting.com ~all
```

So how to I add these two records together?

Answer (score 8):

Just add another TXT record. You can have more than one. concatenating would make them both invalid, they need to stay separate.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a domain MUST NOT have multiple SPF records, otherwise SPF fails with PermError.

Comment: For most DNS providers this works, but AWS Route 53 does not allow multiple TXT records with the same record name. In this case, all the TXT records are actually one record and the values are separated by newlines. See the answer from *Niall Mac An Rí*.

Answer (score 1):

I've just added site verification txt record to an existing. Just make sure all records are on their own line and enclosed with double quotes. (AWS Route 53, anyway)

Comment: Hello Niall, thanks for your answer and welcome to stack overflow. This answer doesn't seem very clear, do you think you could make the wording a bit clearer - instructive on how someone would solve the problem?